# Finding specific elements of array with images

Tags: swift

I have a program that displays a random card when you click the screen, and then removes that card from the card deck. But I also want to check if the random card is either of the picture cards in the deck (so jack, king, queen or ace), and then do some stuff if it is one of those. Anyone know how I can do it? When I try to check if the random card is equal to for example cardDeck[0] (the first card in the deck is a picture card), I get an error:

Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage' to type 'Int'
Thanks for all help!

My code looks like this:

```
var cardDeck = [card1,card2,card2 etc....]

var randomCard: Int = 0
var cardPosition = 0

//row1card1

@IBAction func row1card1tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    randomCard = Int.random(in: 0...51)


    if cardDeck.count > randomCard + 1 {

        if randomCard == cardDeck[0] {
            //do stuff here

        } else {
        row1card1.image = cardDeck[randomCard+1]
        cardDeck.remove(at: randomCard)
        print("removed:" + "\(cardDeck[randomCard])")
        score += 2
        currentPoints.text = "\(score)"
        }
```

Comment: Is your cardDeck an array of images?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan yes, it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your randomCard variable is an Int and you’re trying to compare that with an element from cardDeck which is an image. That’s why you are getting the above exception.

```
if randomCard == 0 {
   //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: ohh I see, thanks. I tried changing it to if randomCard == cardDeck[#imageLiteral(resourceName: "AC")]
but then I get this error:
Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImage]' with an argument of type 'UIImage'

would you be able to help me out if you know how I should do it?

Comment: You could have simply checked the index value alone it seems.

Comment: then I get this error:
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'UIImage'

Comment: Did you try checking the index like in my updated answer?

Comment: oh of course I didn't think of that. thanks! by the way, how could I put multiple numbers in the if statement, so for example if randomCard == 0, 5, 7, 19 etc..?

Comment: You can have them in an array and check if it contains your randomCard. Like, values.contains(randomCard)

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found that helpful. Cheers.!

Comment: hey again, just one question, how should I write the if statement? 
I tried making an array called pictureCards and putting all the picture cards in it, but if pictureCards.contains(randomCard) gives me the error again:
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203867/discussion-between-subramanian-mariappan-and-lamalama69).

Comment: hey, i'm not able to send messages to you in chat again because i don't have 20 reputation. would u contact me again there if you have time? i have a question

Comment: You can post that as a different question.

Comment: thanks, I just did! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250497/do-stuff-if-variable-to-specific-element-of-array