# Do stuff if variable == to specific element of array

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a program that displays cards in a pyramid in 5 rows, so first row is 5 cards, second row is 4 cards and so on...

When the user clicks the back of a card it displays a random card. If that card is one of the pictured cards, the program gives an alert. If not, it removes the random card from the cardDeck array then continues.

But I have a bug while checking for the pictured cards. Sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it does not. So for example on the first row if I get a picture card, it gives the alert. But if it's not a picture card on the first row, but maybe on the second, it sometimes displays the wrong card and then alerts me saying its a picture card.

I'm guessing my error is in the + or - signs I have put in, but I can't figure it out. This is my code:

```
var randomCard: Int = 0
var cardPosition = 0
var cardDeck = [card0, card1, card2, card3 etc...]


let pictureCards = [0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 25, 26, 36, 37, 38, 39, 49, 50, 51]


//row1card1


@IBAction func row1card1tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    randomCard = Int.random(in: 0...51)

    if cardDeck.count > randomCard + 1 {
        if pictureCards.contains(randomCard) {
            print("current random card: " + "\(randomCard)")
            print("bildekort")
            row1card1.image = cardDeck[randomCard]


            let lossAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Feil", message: "Bildekort! Start på nytt", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            lossAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(lossAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)



        } else {
            row1card1.image = cardDeck[randomCard+1]
            cardDeck.remove(at: randomCard)
            print("removed card number: " + "\(randomCard)")
            score += 2
            currentPoints.text = "\(score)"

            row1card1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            row1card2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            row1card3.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            row1card4.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            row1card5.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example value of randomCard when you got the alert wrong?

Comment: one time, I got the card 2, and it gave me the alert saying it was a picture card. but another time, I got a picture card, and it did not alert me at all. It looks like it messes up as I go up the rows

Comment: so just now in one simulation: first and second row were not picture cards, then I click the third row and its a 2, but alerts me that its a picture card

Comment: and in another simulation: first row is not a picture card, second row was a picture card but did not alert me

Comment: I think things gets messed up because you do `cardDeck.remove(at: randomCard)` which mean further access to the `cardDeck` array might point to the wrong element. You seem to be asking a lot of question in relation to this game your writing, it's good you are making progress but maybe it is time to learn how  the debugger works so that you can sort this kind of problems yourself.